# Ruby: How to remove specific digits from integers that are inside an array?

Tags: arrays, ruby, type-conversion, enumerable

I'm new to programming. I would like to take an array of Integers, like `[155, 151, 2, 15]` and remove a specific digit, in this case 5, and add up the new numbers.  I've broken this problem up into smaller steps, and gotten the result I wanted. I'm just wondering if there are easier ways to do a problem like this? Maybe a different method I could use?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is the code I have:

```
 arr = [155, 151, 2, 15]
# goal: remove the 5 digit from values and add 
#       new numbers together --> 1 + 11 + 2 + 1 == 15

# convert to arr of strings and delete zeros
str_arr = []
arr.each do |el|
  str_arr << el.to_s.delete('5')
end

# convert to arr of nums
num_arr = []
str_arr.each do |el|
  num_arr << el.to_i
end

# reduce num_arr
num_arr.reduce(:+)
```

Comment: Instead of pushing elements to an external array, use `map` to return an array of mapped values. E.g., your first example `arr.map { |e| e.to_s.delete('5') }`

Comment: How about `require 'json';  JSON.parse([155, 151, 2, 15].to_json.delete('5')).sum #=> 15`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you can use `map` instead each, this way you avoid having to push to a new initialized array each element transformed inside the block, like:

```
p [155, 151, 2, 15].map { |el| el.to_s.delete('5').to_i }.reduce(:+)
# 15
```

If using ruby 2.4 or higher you can use [`Enumerable#sum`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum) instead reduce (which seems to be a faster option).

```
p [155, 151, 2, 15].sum { |el| el.to_s.delete('5').to_i }
# 15
```

Comment: or `[155, 151, 2, 15].sum { |el| el.to_s.delete('5').to_i }`

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = [155, 151, 2, 15]

arr.sum { |n| (n.digits - [5]).reverse.join.to_i }
  #=> 15
```

Comment: `digits` is available from Ruby 2.4 onwards.

Comment: Thanks, @StefanPochmann. I forgot that `digits` returns the digits in low to high order. I think that adding `reverse` fixes that but it makes the solution less desirable.

Comment: Yeah, that's a bummer. I wish there was a method for the opposite direction, from digit array to Integer. But apparently they forgot that.

Comment: Anyone know why `Integer#digits` reverses the digits?

Comment: @SagarPandya I read somewhere a while ago it was because they, essentially `divmod` by ten pushing to an array as they go (thus lopping off the least significant digits first) and then once it was in the array they could reverse it or they could leave it. They decided if we needed it in order we can reverse the array as easily as they can, so why waste the time doing work that not everyone would need and that was super easy for us to do if we did. But I can't find where I read it...might not be official, could've just been me trying to rationalize it.

Comment: @SagarPandya a place-value representation also makes it easier to convert the digits back to an integer: `digits.each_with_index.sum { |d, i| d * base ** i }`

Answer (score 0):

using `eval`:

```
eval(arr.join('+').delete('5'))    
#=> 15
```

using `inject`:

```
arr.inject(0){|sum, element| element.to_s.delete('5').to_i + sum } 
#=> 15
```

The solution using `eval` is more fun, but the solution using `inject` is arguably easier to understand. Cheers.